# Closure on collection that doesn't need to return anything

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures

I'm trying to write a function to add attributes to an `NSAttributedString`. I have passed in a dictionary to the function like...

```
 tag      attributes
[String : [String : Any]]
```

These (the tag and the attributes) will then be passed into another function to add the attributes inside the given tag.

```
func addAttributes(attributes: [String: Any], forTag tag: String)
```

I can just do...

```
for (tag, attributes) in dictionary
```

but is there a closure way of doing this?

If I use flat map...

```
dictionary.flatMap { addAtritbutes(attributes: $1, insideTag: $0) }
```

Then it complains that I'm not returning anything/using the result of the call. Is there a function that will allow me to do this without warnings?

Thanks

Comment: Introduce a return value to `addAttributes()`.

Comment: Closing as dupe. Couldn't find that one, thanks @MartinR I can't delete so voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach` closure for that.

```
dictionary.forEach {
    addAtritbutes(attributes: $0.value, insideTag: $0.key)
}
```